# Exception not being thrown in Mockito Unit test

Tags: java, junit, mockito, testng

I have a Unit test that keeps failing, because I'm expecting it to throw an exception, but it won't.

The UT is a little confusing, so I'll step through it.
I have a date object, that in happy path will get formatted and returned. However, this test case is in the case an exception gets thrown, then nothing should change in the formatting of the date. However the exception isn't being thrown here

```
public void testGetMyObjectJPE() throws JsonProcessingException {
    MyObject myObject = Mockito.spy(generateMyObject());
    ObjectMapper mapper = Mockito.mock(ObjectMapper.class);
    Date testCreateDate = new Date();

    Mockito.when(myObject.getCreateTime()).thenReturn(testCreateDate);
    Mockito.when(mapper.writeValueAsString(myObject.getCreateTime())).thenThrow(JsonProcessingException.class);
    Mockito.when(myObject.getCreateTime()).thenReturn(testCreateDate);

    MySecObject c = myMapper.getMyObject(myObject, null);
    assertEquals(testCreateDate.toString(), c.getCreateTime());
}
```

This is the code I'm testing:

```
private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

public MySecObj getMyObject(@NotNull MyObject myObject,
        final MyThirdObj myThirdObj) {
    mapper.setDateFormat(new ISO8601DateFormat());
    MySecObj c = new MySecObj();
    c.setId(mySecObj.getId());
    
    // timestamps
    if (mysecObj.getCreateTime() != null) {
        try {
            c.setCreateTime(mapper.writeValueAsString(mySecObj.getCreateTime()).replaceAll("\"", ""));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException jpe) {
            Logger.warn("JSON processing exception for create time " + mySecObj.getCreateTime());
            c.setCreateTime(mySecObj.getCreateTime().toString());
        }
    }

    mapper(c, mySecObj, myThirdObj);
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You instruct the mock ObjectMapper to throw, but the code under test doesn't use that mock mapper; it uses its own mapper which it constructs by calling the ObjectMapper constructor.

It is necessary to inject the mock mapper into the code, either by passing it as an additional parameter, or through dependency injection. In general, avoid new-ing up dependencies. I'm not sure what dependency injection framework you're using, if any. Where I work, we would do something like the following with Spring Boot:

```
// in a configuration class somewhere in the project
@Configuration
public class SpiderConfig {
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setDateFormat(new ISO8601DateFormat());
        // any other configuration of standard project mapper
        return mapper;
    }
}

// in the service which uses the ObjectMapper
@Service
public class SpiderService {
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    // etc.
}

// in the unit test
@Mock
private ObjectMapper mapper;

@InjectMocks
private SpiderService service;

@Test
public void testGetMyObjectJPE() throws JsonProcessingException {
    when(mapper.writeValueAsString(...)...
```

When the service runs normally, a real ObjectMapper will be injected into the autowired field, but when the unit test runs it will inject a mock ObjectMapper.

Of course, if you are not using Spring Boot, there are other ways to inject the mock. The simplest, using no DI framework, would be to provide a setter for the mapper field, or use reflection in the unit test to set the mapper.

Additionally, this code:

```
Mockito.when(mapper.writeValueAsString(myObject.getCreateTime())).thenThrow(JsonProcessingException.class);
Mockito.when(myObject.getCreateTime()).thenReturn(testCreateDate);
```

Should probably be:

```
Mockito.when(mapper.writeValueAsString(testCreateDate)).thenThrow(JsonProcessingException.class);
Mockito.when(myObject.getCreateTime()).thenReturn(testCreateDate);
```

In the first case, you are mocking the `writeValueAsString` method to throw whenever it is called with whatever your object's `getCreateTime` method will return, but it is the actual return value after you've just created the object, *not* the `testCreateDate` that you are *about* to mock the spy to return.

When the actual call occurs in your code under test, it passes the `testCreateDate` which does not match the value you've told it to throw for, so the mock ObjectMapper probably just returns `null` or `""` or something like that. However, without the mock mapper being injected, this won't matter and if you've replaced the value with `any()` then the specific value is not relevant.

(By the way, I hope you know that `java.util.Date` is considered horribly obsolete and broken these days, and should only be used by legacy code.)

Comment: No, I tried this and I tried using any() in the first when, none of it had helped. Yes I'm also trying to upgrade Date, but codebase is so large it's a nightmare.

Comment: I just noticed that the code under test instantiates the mapper with `new ObjectMapper()`. So your mock ObjectMapper is not getting injected into the code and isn't used when the test runs.